Vibrancy extension not working on VS Code, throwing error on startup
When I try to reload Vibrancy continued extension in VS Code it doesn't work, throws the error

Couldn't open custom import file: "$theme-style$"

I tried reinstalling the extension but still throws error.
This extension was working fine few days ago but now it's giving error. How can I fix this issue?


On the screen shot you can see a "Issues" link under "Resources" section. That's where to report issues like this.
